# Using lapply to pass labels to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, functional-programming, lapply, sapply

I am trying to use lapply to loop through a list of vectors containing plot labels. The list contains vectors. The first element of the vector is the plot title, then the x axis label, and then the y axis label. I want to avoid writing any for loops. I can't figure out how to reference the. The code below is the closest I could come up with, but it just outputs `NULL` 3 times.

```
library(tidyverse)

plot.labels <- list(c("Title1","Xlab1","ylab1"),c("Title2","Xlab2","ylab1"),c("Title3","Xlab3","ylab1"))

plotter <- function(plotdata=d, xvar=cond,lab = NULL){
  ggplot(data = plotdata, aes( x = xvar , y = scale(vowmeanf0) ))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(title = lab[1],
         x = lab[2],
         y = lab[3])
}

lapply(plot.labels, function(x){
  for(df in 1:length(plot.labels)){
    plotter(x[df])
  }
} )
```

Comment: `lapply` should look more like this. You should never loop within `lapply` because `lapply` is essentially a wrapper for a `for` loop to begin with. `lapply(plot.labels, function(x) plotter(plotdata = d, xvar = cond, lab = x))`

Comment: In this case, `x` is the iterator, which will be passed to each set of values from `plot.labels`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lapply should look more like this. You should never loop within lapply because lapply is essentially a wrapper for a for loop to begin with. lapply(plot.labels, function(x) plotter(plotdata = d, xvar = cond, lab = x)) – Mako212

That worked

```
library(tidyverse)

plot.labels <- list(c("Title1","Xlab1","Ylab1"),c("Title2","Xlab2","Ylab2"),c("Title3","Xlab3","Ylab3"))

plotter <- function(plotdata = NULL, xvar = NULL ,lab = NULL){
  ggplot(data = plotdata, aes( x = xvar , y = scale(vowmeanf0) ))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(title = lab[1],
         x = lab[2],
         y = lab[3])
}

lapply(plot.labels, function(x) plotter(plotdata = d, xvar = "cond", lab = x))
```